# how can I correct sum function?

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote my function that calculate heart rate target for sports, every things is true but in switch function, first case when every thing is do, last sum in function don't do. for example if someone have 20 years old and 50 rest heart rate in minutes.they heart rate target have to be 102.5, but it's 53 because formula don't do last sum. 
(mhr*0.35+hr)....hr don't sum.

```js
function heartR() {
  var y = document.getElementsByName("year5")[0].value;
  var hr = document.getElementsByName("RBR")[0].value;
  var gole = document.getElementsByName("gole")[0];
  var a3 = gole.options[gole.selectedIndex].text;
  var mhr = (220 - y) - hr;
  switch (a3) {
    case "تمرین برای افراد دارای بیماریهای خاص":
      document.getElementById("heartR").innerHTML = " MinHR= " + (mhr * 0.35 + hr);
      break;
    case "تمرین برای چربی سوزی":
      document.getElementById("heartR").innerHTML = " MinHR= " + (mhr * 0.50 + hr);
      break;
    default:
      document.getElementById("bmr").innerHTML = "شما شدت فعالیت را انتخاب نکرده اید";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sectionmenu">
  <form action="#" target="_self" method="get">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>برآورد ضربان قلب هدف</legend>
      سن (years)<br>
      <input type="number" name="year5" placeholder="30"><br> ضربان قلب استراحت (HR/min)<br>
      <input type="number" name="RBR" placeholder="60"><br> هدف شما<br>
      <select name="gole">
        <option value="special"> تمرین برای افراد دارای بیماریهای خاص</option>
        <option value="fat-burn"> تمرین برای چربی سوزی</option>
        <option value="aerobic"> تمرینات هوازی و استقامتی</option>
        <option value="vo2max"> تمرین برای تقویت حداکثر اکسیژن مصرفی</option>
        <option value="anaerobic"> تمرین برای افزایش ظرفیت بی هوازی</option>
      </select><br><br>
      <input type="button" value="محاسبه" onClick="heartR()" class="button"><br>
      <p id="heartR">

      </p>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `(mhr*0.35+hr)` does not appear in your code.

Comment: You have `(mhr * 0.50 + hr)` in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

The value of hr & mhr is probably considered as a string, therefore JS automatically concatenates the inputs.
Try parseInt() to convert it into number and then calculate the sum as shown below:

```
console.log(parseInt(mhr)*0.35+parseInt(hr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few corrections:

- Element with id `bmr` does not exist, so your `default` case throws an exception.
- Use the option `value` instead of its `text` property to identify the selected option in your switch statement
- Do not use a number as the placeholder for your number inputs, it is misleading, instead set the initial value with the `value` property
- Convert your input values to numbers using the `+` operator.

And the corrected snippet:

```js
function heartR() {
  var y = +document.getElementsByName("year5")[0].value;
  var hr = +document.getElementsByName("RBR")[0].value;
  var gole = document.getElementsByName("gole")[0];
  var a3 = gole.options[gole.selectedIndex].value;
  var mhr = (220 - y) - hr;
  switch (a3) {
    case 'special':
      document.getElementById("heartR").innerHTML = " MinHR= " + (mhr * 0.35 + hr);
      break;
    case 'fat-burn':
      document.getElementById("heartR").innerHTML = " MinHR= " + (mhr * 0.50 + hr);
      break;
    default:
      document.getElementById("bmr").innerHTML = "شما شدت فعالیت را انتخاب نکرده اید";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sectionmenu">
  <form action="#" target="_self" method="get">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>برآورد ضربان قلب هدف</legend>
      سن (years)<br>
      <input type="number" name="year5" value="30"><br> ضربان قلب استراحت (HR/min)<br>
      <input type="number" name="RBR" value="60"><br> هدف شما<br>
      <select name="gole">
        <option value="special"> تمرین برای افراد دارای بیماریهای خاص</option>
        <option value="fat-burn"> تمرین برای چربی سوزی</option>
        <option value="aerobic"> تمرینات هوازی و استقامتی</option>
        <option value="vo2max"> تمرین برای تقویت حداکثر اکسیژن مصرفی</option>
        <option value="anaerobic"> تمرین برای افزایش ظرفیت بی هوازی</option>
      </select><br><br>
      <input type="button" value="محاسبه" onClick="heartR()" class="button"><br>
      <p id="heartR"></p>
      <p id="bmr"></p>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function heartR() {
  var y = document.getElementsByName("year5")[0].value;
  var hr = document.getElementsByName("RBR")[0].value;
  var gole = document.getElementsByName("gole")[0];
  var a3 = gole.options[gole.selectedIndex].text;
  var mhr = (220 - y) - hr;
  switch (a3) {
    case "تمرین برای افراد دارای بیماریهای خاص":
      document.getElementById("heartR").innerHTML = " MinHR= " + (mhr * 0.35 + hr);
      break;
    case "تمرین برای چربی سوزی":
      document.getElementById("heartR").innerHTML = " MinHR= " + (mhr * 0.50 + hr);
      break;
    default:
      document.getElementById("bmr").innerHTML = "شما شدت فعالیت را انتخاب نکرده اید";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sectionmenu">
  <form action="#" target="_self" method="get">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>برآورد ضربان قلب هدف</legend>
      سن (years)<br>
      <input type="number" name="year5" placeholder="30"><br> ضربان قلب استراحت (HR/min)<br>
      <input type="number" name="RBR" placeholder="60"><br> هدف شما<br>
      <select name="gole">
        <option value="special"> تمرین برای افراد دارای بیماریهای خاص</option>
        <option value="fat-burn"> تمرین برای چربی سوزی</option>
        <option value="aerobic"> تمرینات هوازی و استقامتی</option>
        <option value="vo2max"> تمرین برای تقویت حداکثر اکسیژن مصرفی</option>
        <option value="anaerobic"> تمرین برای افزایش ظرفیت بی هوازی</option>
      </select><br><br>
      <input type="button" value="محاسبه" onClick="heartR()" class="button"><br>
      <p id="heartR">

      </p>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

```js
function heartR(){
 var y= document.getElementsByName("year5")[0].value;
 var hr= document.getElementsByName("RBR")[0].value;
 var gole = document.getElementsByName("gole")[0]; 
 var a3=gole.options[gole.selectedIndex].value;
 var mhr= (220 - y)-hr;
 switch (a3) {
  case 'special':
   document.getElementById("heartR").innerHTML= " MinHR= " + (mhr*0.35+parseInt(hr)) + "<br/>" + " MaxHR = " + (mhr*0.45+parseInt(hr));
   break;
  case 'fat-burn':
   document.getElementById("heartR").innerHTML= " MinHR= " + (mhr*0.50+parseInt(hr)) + "<br/>" + " MaxHR = " + (mhr*0.60+parseInt(hr));
   break;
  case 'aerobic':
   document.getElementById("heartR").innerHTML= " MinHR= " + (mhr*0.55+parseInt(hr)) + "<br/>" + " MaxHR = " + (mhr*0.70+parseInt(hr));
   break;
  case 'vo2max':
   document.getElementById("heartR").innerHTML= " MinHR= " + (mhr*0.75+parseInt(hr)) + "<br/>" + " MaxHR = " + (mhr*0.85+parseInt(hr));
   break;
  case 'anaerobic':
   document.getElementById("heartR").innerHTML= " MinHR= " + (mhr*0.85+parseInt(hr)) + "<br/>" + " MaxHR = " + (mhr*1+parseInt(hr));
   break;
  default:
   document.getElementById("heartR").innerHTML="شما شدت فعالیت را انتخاب نکرده اید";
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="sectionmenu">
   <form action="#" target="_self" method="get">
     <fieldset>
       <legend>برآورد ضربان قلب هدف</legend>
        سن (years)<br>
        <input type="number" name="year5" value="30"><br>
        ضربان قلب استراحت (HR/min)<br>
        <input type="number" name="RBR" value="60"><br>
      هدف شما<br>
     <select name="gole">
      <option value="special"> تمرین برای افراد دارای بیماریهای خاص</option>
      <option value="fat-burn"> تمرین برای چربی سوزی</option>
      <option value="aerobic"> تمرینات هوازی و استقامتی</option>
      <option value="vo2max"> تمرین برای تقویت حداکثر اکسیژن مصرفی</option>
      <option value="anaerobic"> تمرین برای افزایش ظرفیت بی هوازی</option>
     </select><br><br>
       <input type="button" value="محاسبه" onClick="heartR()" class="button"><br>
     <p id="heartR">
     
     </p>
     </fieldset>
   </form>
</div>
```